# Disable link with pointer-events but keep active the :hover event

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover, pointer-events

I wan't to disable a link in my home page with the attribute selector and the `pointer-events: disable;` but I would like to maintain the :hover effect.

This is the CSS:

```
Section#thumbnails .thumb a[title="Yorokobu"]{
    pointer-events: none !important;
    display: block !important;
    cursor: default;
  }
```

And this the website: www.rafagarces.com/work

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could add the `:hover` state to a parent element.

```css
section#thumbnails .thumb a[title="Yorokobu"] {
    pointer-events: none !important;
    display: block !important;
    cursor: default;
}

section#thumbnails .thumb:hover a[title="Yorokobu"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="thumbnails">
  <span class="thumb">
    <a title="Yorokobu">
      Test
    </a>
  </span>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your answer:

```
section#thumbnails .thumb a[title="Yorokobu"]:hover {
    pointer-events: visible !important;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

Comment: This don't works :/